# Rock, paper, scissors game experimetal

Tags: java

Good day guys, So i wanted to create a rock, paper, scissors game between the player and the machine, then score the player and machine based on the results. The problem is that my scores always equates to 0, i don't understand!
Please help guys, I'm also a newbie...here is the code

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.Random;

public class Game2

{

    //Declaring my random object

    private static Random random = new Random();


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        //Declaring my variables
        int playerScore = 0;
        int machineScore = 0;

        int totPlayerScore = 0;
        int totMachineScore = 0;

        //Instantiating my list object
        List<String> dice = new ArrayList<>();

        //We gon rename scissors to cuts for a shorter input
        //Adding values to the list
        dice.add("rock");
        dice.add("paper");
        dice.add("cuts");


        //Paper beats rock, rock beats cuts, cuts beats paper
        //For loop to play the game 3 times
        for(int i = 0; i <3; i++)
        {

            //User input
            String strInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter paper, rock or cuts");


            //Randomizing the list
            int index = random.nextInt(dice.size());

            //If statement to see if the usr or machine won
            if(strInput.toLowerCase() == "paper" && dice.get(index) == "rock")//win
            {

                playerScore += 1;

                totPlayerScore += playerScore;
            }
            else if(strInput.toLowerCase() == "rock" && dice.get(index) == "cuts")//win
            {
                playerScore += 1;

                totPlayerScore += playerScore;
            }
            else if(strInput.toLowerCase() == "cuts" && dice.get(index) == "paper")//Win
            {
                playerScore += 1;

                totPlayerScore += playerScore;
            }
            else if(strInput.toLowerCase() == "paper" && dice.get(index) == "paper")//Draw
            {
                playerScore = playerScore;

                totPlayerScore += playerScore;
            }
            else if(strInput.toLowerCase() == "rock" && dice.get(index) == "rock")//Draw
            {
                playerScore = playerScore;

                totPlayerScore += playerScore;
            }
            else if(strInput.toLowerCase() == "cuts" && dice.get(index) == "cuts")//Draw
            {
                playerScore = playerScore;

                totPlayerScore += playerScore;

            }//End of player if statement

            //Start of machine if statement
            if(strInput.toLowerCase() == "rock" && dice.get(index) == "paper")//win
            {

                machineScore += 1;

                totMachineScore += machineScore;
            }
            else if(strInput.toLowerCase() == "cuts" && dice.get(index) == "rock")//win
            {
                machineScore += 1;

                totMachineScore += machineScore;
            }
            else if(strInput.toLowerCase() == "paper" && dice.get(index) == "cuts")//Win
            {
                machineScore += 1;

                totMachineScore += machineScore;
            }

             //End of if statement


            //Displaying user Results
            System.out.println("User draw: " + strInput.toLowerCase() + " Machine draw: " + dice.get(index).toLowerCase());
            System.out.println("User Score " + playerScore + " Machine Score " + machineScore +  "\n");


        }//End of for loop


        //Displaying my final results
        System.out.println("User Final score: " + totPlayerScore + " Machine Final score: " + totMachineScore + "\n");


        //If statement to see who won, hte player or machine
        if(totPlayerScore > totMachineScore)
        {
            System.out.println("The Player won!!!");
        }
        else if(totPlayerScore == totMachineScore)
        {
            System.out.println("Its a draw!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The Machine won!!! \n");
        }

        //Console message to end the program and game
        System.out.println("Game over!!!!!");

    }//End of main

}//End of class
```

Comment: besides the comparison way, try to avoid duplicating code. you are repeating conditions, nested conditions will do the same work, but more efficiënt, and the code is easier to read

Comment: yea, i changed my code and used nested if statements thanx for that, but my code still produces a 0 score...

Comment: are you still comparing them using the == operator?

Comment: yes, should i use a different operator? if so which?

Comment: Oh ya, i just saw the mistake, I'm supposed to use the .equals() method to compare strings and not the == operator, and my program is running...awe thanx man...